# Devise log in with github goes to a 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, devise, omniauth, github-api

I am using Devise, and enabling Github omniauth.

When I click "sign in with github", I get redirected to a 404 not found page on github. (Link below)

I noticed that in the url, the client_id parameter is empty. Is this normal? Is there anything else that looks strange about the URL?

There are a lot of files involved with this set up, but I can paste any snippets that may be relevant.

[The URL that I get taken to after clicking sign in with Github:](https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Floc.blockspring.com%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Aemail)

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?
  client_id=
  &redirect_uri=http://loc.mynewapp.com:3000/users/auth/github/callback
  &response_type=code
  &scope=user:email
```

Comment: It's not normal that the client_id is empty. It's needed for the OAuth flow and that's the reason why you're seeing the 404. Try manually setting the client_id in that URL and see if that fixes things. And then try figuring out why the client_id is not being set.

Comment: Figured it out! When I created the Github app, I put in all the fields as if they were on production (e.g. http://myactualsite.com) instead of for local development (e.g. http://loc.myactualsite.com:3000). That fixed it. I'll just create 2 apps which seems easy enough.